# Fetch no-cors Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using react and webpack.. why does the code below result in an error: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input(…)`? Thanks

```
    fetch(feedURL, {"mode": "no-cors"})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(data){

        this.setState({
            data: data
        })

    }.bind(this));
```

Comment: is the response valid JSON?

Comment: Since you aren't checking the type of response that you are getting and not setting any accept header either, you might not have a failsafe for a scenario when the response that you get is not of JSON type. Might be a possible cause of the problem.

Comment: Testing the JSON raw data is valid, but the URL to the file hosted on a CDN is not valid. `Invalid encoding, expecting UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32.` Any thoughts on how I can fix?

Comment: The response ought to have header `Content-Type: application/json`. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

To better understand your error, add a catch case to your fetch request.

Also, if you use arrow functions, you don't need to bind(this);

```
fetch(feedURL, {"mode": "no-cors"})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    this.setState({
        data: data
    });
})
.catch(resp => {
    console.error(resp);
});
```